# How to overloading an operator in SystemVerilog

Tags: operator-overloading, system-verilog

Does anyone have a working example for overloading an operator in SystemVerilog? I read the spec and tried "bind" with Questasim 10.3. But there's no luck.

Comment: What do you mean by "But there's no luck"? Did you get any error? What (and how exactly) are you trying to overload?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think any tool supports this construct.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Although the answer is a little bit disappointing